# GLJPanel double buffering

Tags: java, macos, opengl, jogl

I'm using JOGL on OS X, and trying to create a double-buffered GLJPanel, but it just doesn't work. Here's what I'm doing:

```
GLCapabilities glCapabilities = new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL4));
glCapabilities.setDoubleBuffered(true);
System.out.println(glCapabilities.getDoubleBuffered());
GLJPanel glPanel = new GLJPanel(glCapabilities);
System.out.println(glPanel.getRequestedGLCapabilities().getDoubleBuffered());
```

And this is the output:

```
true
false
```

I'm logging the requested capabilities, not even the chosen capabilities... So it should be the same as the one I'm passing to the constructor, right? 
BTW of course further down the line after the initialisation, the chosen capabilities will also have double-buffering turned off, and then the whole rendering goes into the trash.

How come that the panel just ignores the passed-in capabilities which clearly has `doubleBuffered` set to `true`?

Comment: Rather call getChosenGLCapabilities() instead of getRequestedGLCapabilities(). Please read again our documentation. Moreover, JOGL makes its best to pick a capabilities object close to the one you request but sometimes it can't pick exactly what you look for.